# Is there a way to view web images from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, images

I want to be able to view the images inside a repository about wallpapers. Going through every image takes to long with the browser. I wonder if exists a program which I can accomplish this, view images from http

Comment: Is this a local repository or a remote repository? How do you access the images (the browser implies via HTTP(S))? Did you use the browser tools to find out why it takes so long going through the images?

Comment: It's a remote repo, the protocol is https (but I don't  difference on this). Let's say [this](https://gitlab.com/OldTechBloke/dotfiles/-/tree/master/wallpaper) as an example. To view several wallpapers It is necessary to click on the image and the go back to the tree to again click on another image

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timg` the installation instruction is available on [this git repository](https://github.com/hzeller/timg)

To display an image in the terminal:

```
timg url_to_image
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [fim](https://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/) but unfortunately, you can only see local images.

Answer (score 0):

Every image you want to view has to be downloaded first, that's possibly the part that takes the most time since wallpaper images tend to be rather large.

You can either download all images to your local disk using `wget` or `curl` with the mirror option or even `git` to clone the repository that you mentioned in the comment. This will take even more time but you can use it to do something else. Afterwards you use a local viewer for images and quickly open one image after the other.

Another option is to open the images in another browser tab. The download won't get faster that way, but you can go faster back to the index and you can even look at one image while your browser is loading other images in other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount the git repository with something like [gitfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitfs), [gitfuse](https://github.com/davesque/gitfuse), [slothfs](https://github.com/google/slothfs),...

Once mounted you would then use the same tools you use to see images locally.

But if you have enough space, I think nothing beats downloading the zip or tar.bz2 version of the image repository to your local machine. Depending on your resources, you could also use `fuse-zip` so that you don't even have to care about unpacking those zip files.